# How to get the x-y coordinates of TextInput's cursor in React Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I want to get the x-y coordinates of a TextInput's cursor. I want to anchor another component above the cursor and need a position of the cursor.

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Image of a menu apppearing on top of a cursor]

Answer (score 0):

TextInputs can receive press events, and they contain information about the press locations. While this where tell you where the press occurred, it may not actually reflect where the cursor is placed. Pressing the far right edge of the input will place the cursor at the end of the text pressed, rather than the end of input view, and presses will have different y positions even though the cursor's y position doesnt change for single line inputs.

You could take things a step further and use the cursor's index,input's fontSize and input's layout to try to estimate the cursor position (what I have isnt accurate but maybe some fine tuning will produced desired results):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const fontSize = 14;

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('some placeholder');
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = React.useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [estimatedPosition, setEstimatedPosition] = React.useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const [inputLayout, setInputLayout] = React.useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        Cursor Position: {Math.floor(cursorPosition.x)},{' '}
        {Math.floor(cursorPosition.y)}
        {'\n'}
        Estimated Position: {Math.floor(estimatedPosition.x)},{' '}
        {Math.floor(estimatedPosition.y)}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{ fontSize, borderBottomWidth: 1, marginVertical: 10 }}
        value={text}
        onChangeText={setText}
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          setInputLayout(nativeEvent.layout);
        }}
        onSelectionChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          // selectionChange provides cursor index
          const cursorIndex = nativeEvent.selection.start;
          console.log(cursorIndex);
          const x =
            (inputLayout.left || inputLayout.x) + cursorIndex * fontSize * 0.5;
          // if you have multiline inputs struggle will find u
          const y = inputLayout.top || inputLayout.y;
          setEstimatedPosition({ x, y });
        }}
        onPressOut={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          setCursorPosition({
            x: nativeEvent.locationX,
            y: nativeEvent.pageY,
          });
        }}
      />
      <Text>
        Pink dot is estimated position. Red dot is press position. Please note
        that keyboard corrections arent accounted for so closing the keyboard
        will provide a more accurate reading. onPressOut also doesnt function
        on the web
      </Text>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.dot,
          { left: estimatedPosition.x, top: estimatedPosition.y },
        ]}
      />
      <View
        style={[
          styles.dot,
          {
            left: cursorPosition.x,
            top: cursorPosition.y,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  dot: {
    width: 16,
    height: 16,
    borderRadius: 8,
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
});
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/x4vT_JA9w)